# My integer array has an issue of "Too many characters in a character literal"

Tags: c#

I made the int array
`int[] intLetterValue = { '1','2','5','7','3','1','6','3','10' };`
and it comes up with the error "too many characters in the character literal", but only for the 10. So I tried changing the `'10'` to `"10"`, however instead of fixing it, it bought up the new error "cannot implcitly convert string to int". I've looked, but I can't find any solutions on the internet anywhere.
Help would be appriciated, thanks

Comment: You know you are creating an array with integers 49, 50, 51, here ... the ascii-values of the characters ?

Answer (score 4):

Well, `'10'` is neither a valid `char` nor a valid `int`. You surely want `new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }`, without all those single-quotes.

Just for completeness you can also do this:

```
new int[] { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' }
```

The reason this compiles (notice that I omitted `'10'`because of the reason mentioned above), is that `char` can implicetly be converted to `int`. Doing so will just return the characters unicode-codepoint. For instance the **character** `'1'` matches the code`int` 49.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I forgot that you did not need to use quotes with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared an array of `int` types, which causes issues.

Enclosing the numbers in single quotes creates `char` types. `'10'` is not a valid `char` because chars are one-character values.

Next, you're running into issues because double quotes are string literals, when you want `int`s.

Simply write:

`int[] intLetterValue = { 1, 2, 5, 7, 3, 1, 6, 3, 10 };`

Comment: Referring to this bit in the question: So I tried changing the `'10'` to `"10"`

Answer (score 0):

```
char c = '1';

int i = 1;

string s = "1";
```

These are completely different things.

Considering you are declaring `int`s, you shouldn't use `char`s' semantic.

It isn't returning you an error for the first numbers only because `char` can implicitly be converted to `int`, but that `int` is the `char` converted to its' position in ascii.